# how do i align the span tags in div tag in a well designed way?

Tags: javascript, css, html

Well Im stucked at this point.please take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/karthik64/5jhgF/3/

Okay first enter some input into the input box and hit enter you would see a span element added to the div and try to input some more values and 
I guess you got what the problem is.Could anyone tell me how do i fit those `<span>` tags in `<div>` tag in a nice manner.

I have set my div tag width and using javscript I add some elements to div tag and  I get some kind of wierd bugs something like for example . if user enters dennis ritchie , steve jobs and bill gates my code works likes this

```
   ..dennis ritchie..  ..steve jobs.. ..bil
   l gates..
```

Instead it should be like this

```
  ..dennis ritchie.. ..steve jobs..
  ..bill gates..
```

if it cannot fit the span tag in that remaining space, I want the whole span tag element jump to next line instead of breaking the span tag value how do i do that .please help me with this.any help is greatly appreciated.Thanks

Comment: I'm not seeing anything but an empty box at your jsfiddle link using Firefox 9.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<span>`s are not [block-level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Block-level_elements) and are not rendered like you describe by default (they wrap with text). Apply the CSS [`display: inline-block;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/display) to your spans to stop them from wrapping.

Comment: Thanks it worked but how do i insert some space between new lines in div tag? I would accept your answe if you let me know it and +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

On newer browsers, add `display: inline-block;` to the `.music_elements` style rule.

On older browsers, `float: left;` might work.